# Get Users Activity LOG

Tags: unix, centos

How we can get users activity log for UNIX system (Cent OS)
I mean everything user has done after connection,some kind of key-logger, or action logger ))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the auditd daemon to log access to certain files, depending on your configuration.

see

```
man auditd
```

and

```
man auditd.conf
```